# Trouble getting Ubuntu 12.04 Hyper-V guest to connect to wireless from Windows 8.1 Host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, hyper-v

I'm trying to set up a Ubuntu 12.04 VM using Hyper-V in a Windows 8.1 host.  It runs mostly fine, except that I can't get the internet to work well.  I've followed the instructions at http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/using-your-windows-8-wireless-connection-inside-hyper-v/, and my configuration is:

[image: Settings for VM]

[image: Network settings]

When I boot up the VM, I see Wired Network (Digital Equipment DECchip 21140[FasterNet]) device not ready:

[image: Wired Network (Digital Equipment DECchip 21140(FasterNet) device not ready]

Clicking "Wired connection 1" just results in the icon repeatedly blinking and showing the animation it uses when trying to acquire internet access.  I had originally tried using the "Network Adapter" rather than the "Legacy Network Adapter", and the internet worked sometimes, but only for 2-3 minutes at a time.  However, I can't seem to recreate that state now (I don't get internet access even if I have the configuration as follows):

[image: VM Configuration]

I also tried using an "External" network rather than an "Internal" one, which created a bridge in my network connections, but that resulted in not having internet connectivity on the host.

How do I share my wireless connection between Windows 8.1 and Hyper-V Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Try manually bringing up the file by means of the following command sudo ifconfig eth1 up && dhclient -v eth1

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Network Adapter as "Internal Network" Virtual Switch for your Ubuntu VM (Hyper-V Client)
2. On Host machine, goto "control Panel", "Network and Internet", "Network and Sharing Center"
3. Left click on Host "connections" (This is the Host machines physical wireless adapter)
4. In pop-up window, click on properties
5. Click on "Sharing"
6. Check box "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet Connection
7. Under "Home Networking Connection), select name of Virtual Switch you created at step 1.

Should work now. Just FYI, the above steps are NOT necessary if you are creating a Windows VM.